# Rust code of a tree fractal

Tags: beginner, image, rust, graphics, fractals

I just picked up Rust recently and this is my first program (longer than 10 lines at least) so I'm looking for constructs that are more native and natural to Rust. I come from a c++/ python background. If there are some more compile-time optimizations that would also be nice since I am interested in zero overhead abstractions.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::cmp;

const SCALING_FACTOR: f64 = 1.4 as f64;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct RGB {
    red: u8,
    green: u8,
    blue: u8
}

fn serialize_rgb(pixels: &Vec<RGB>, size: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
    // for saving to a file. Is there any way we could do this
    // without constructing a new array? Would be much faster
    let mut output: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(size * 3);
    for pix in pixels {
        output.push(pix.red);
        output.push(pix.green);
        output.push(pix.blue);
    }
    output
}

struct Canvas {
    // Using 1D array so the bytes are together in memory, should be more efficient than Vec<Vec>
    // since that would store pointers to vectors?
    pixels: Vec<RGB>,
    width: i32,
    height: i32
}

impl Canvas {
    fn set_colour(&mut self, x: i32, y: i32, colour: &RGB) {
        // make this more natural? In C++ you can overload () to get a functor
        if x > 0 && y > 0 &&  x < self.width && y <  self.height {
            self.pixels[(self.width * y + x) as usize] = colour.clone();
        }
    }

    fn write_to_file(&mut self, filename: &str) {
        let mut file = init_ppm(filename, self.width, self.height);
        file.write_all(&serialize_rgb(&self.pixels, (self.width * self.height) as usize)).expect("error");
        /* slow
        for pixel in &self.pixels {
            file.write_all(&[pixel.red, pixel.green, pixel.blue]).expect("error writing to a file");
        }*/
    }

    fn new(width: i32, height: i32) -> Canvas {
        Canvas {
            width,
            height,
            pixels: vec![RGB{red:0, green:0, blue:0}; (width * height) as usize]
        }
    }

    fn draw_square(&mut self, center: &Point, width: i32, colour: &RGB) {
        for y in cmp::max(0, center.y - width) .. cmp::min(self.height, center.y + width) {
            for x in cmp::max(0, center.x - width) .. cmp::min(self.width, center.x + width) {
                self.set_colour(x ,y, &colour);
            }
        }
    }

    fn draw_line(&mut self, from: &Point, to: &Point, width: i32, colour: &RGB) {
        // function that connects two points on the grid with a line
        if from.x == to.x { // vertical lines
            let startx = cmp::max(from.x - width, 0);
            let endx = cmp::min(from.x + width, self.width);
            let endy = cmp::max(from.y, to.y) + 1;
            let starty = cmp::min(from.y, to.y);
            for y in starty .. endy {
                for x in  startx .. endx {
                    self.set_colour(x, y, colour);
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            let k = (to.y - from.y) as f64 / (to.x - from.x) as f64;
            let n = to.y as f64 - k * to.x as f64;
            let lower = cmp::min(from.x, to.x);
            let upper = cmp::max(from.x, to.x) + 1;
            for x in lower .. upper {
                // We colour y's as a function of x's
                self.draw_square(
                    &Point {x: x, y: (k * x as f64 + n) as i32},
                    width,
                    colour
                );
            }
            if k.abs() > 1.0 {
                // for steep lines, we also have to consider x as a function of y to get good results
                let lower = cmp::min(from.y, to.y);
                let upper = cmp::max(from.y, to.y) + 1;
                for y in lower .. upper {
                    self.draw_square(
                        &Point {x: ((y as f64 - n) / k) as i32, y: y},
                        width,
                        colour
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

fn rotate_point(center: &Point, point: &Point, angle: f64) -> Point {
    // also scales down a bit
    let (sin, cos) = angle.sin_cos();
    let translated = Point {x: ((point.x - center.x) as f64 / SCALING_FACTOR) as i32,
                            y: ((point.y - center.y) as f64 / SCALING_FACTOR) as i32};
    let rotated = Point {x: (translated.x as f64 * cos - translated.y as f64 * sin) as i32,
                         y: (translated.x as f64 * sin + translated.y as f64 * cos) as i32
    };
    Point {x: rotated.x + center.x, y: rotated.y + center.y}
}

fn init_ppm(filename: &str, width: i32, height: i32) -> File {
    let mut file = File::create(format!("{}.ppm",filename)).expect("couldn't create");
    file.write_all(format!("P6 {} {} 255 ", width, height).as_bytes()).expect("error writing to a file");
    file
}

struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}

fn main() {
    const WIDTH: i32 = 1500;
    const HEIGHT: i32 = 1500;
    let mut picture = Canvas::new(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    draw_tree(&mut picture,
              &Point {x: WIDTH/2, y: HEIGHT},
              &Point {x: WIDTH/2, y: 3*HEIGHT/4},
              15,
              &RGB {red: 255, blue: 255, green: 255},
              0.6,
              2);
    picture.write_to_file("test");
}


fn draw_tree(mut canvas: &mut Canvas, prev: &Point, next: &Point, iter: i32, colour: &RGB, angle: f64, branches: i32) {
    // recursively generates branches.
    if iter == 0 {
        return;
    }
    canvas.draw_line(prev, next, 1, colour);
    let prev = Point {x: 2 * next.x - prev.x, y: 2 * next.y - prev.y};

    if branches % 2 == 1 {
        draw_tree(&mut canvas, &next, &rotate_point(next, &prev, 0.0), iter - 1, colour, angle, branches);
    }
    for i in 1 .. branches / 2 + 1 {
        // colours are hardcoded currently but that's not really important
        let rot_left = rotate_point(next, &prev, i as f64 * angle);
        draw_tree(&mut canvas, &next, &rot_left, iter - 1, &RGB{red: 247, green: 97, blue: 74}, angle, branches);

        let rot_right = rotate_point(next, &prev, - i as f64 * angle);
        draw_tree(&mut canvas, &next, &rot_right, iter - 1, &RGB{red: 26, green: 121, blue: 244}, angle, branches);
    }
}
```

End result of the code is a .ppm image file `test.ppm` that looks [image: binary tree image] like this (depending on how you set the settings in main and SCALING_FACTOR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was great work, especially for a first project. 
I made a bunch of changes and tried to comment my reasoning where things stood out. Here's a few things to note:

- Your code was at the size where you could go either way, but I decided to split it up into modules.
- I made `Point` and `Rgb` implement `Copy` since they are just very small collections of numbers. Now you can have functions take those by value, rather than reference.
- I store the color data as bytes rather than `Rgb`s, which lets you write that data directly to the ppm. Another possible way to do it is to use `unsafe` to change a `&[Rgb]` into a `&[u8]`, but it's trickier and you have to be very careful.
- You should generally try to use `usize` when describing the size of something.
- Make it a goal to have doc comments on at least everything public. You can add `#![warn(missing_docs)]` to the top of `main.rs` to help you with this.
- Check out the tools `rustfmt` and `clippy`.

`main.rs`

```
mod canvas;
mod point;
mod rgb;

pub use canvas::Canvas;
pub use point::Point;
pub use rgb::Rgb;

fn main() {
    const WIDTH: usize = 1500;
    const HEIGHT: usize = 1500;

    let mut picture = Canvas::new(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    draw_tree(
        &mut picture,
        Point {
            x: WIDTH as i32 / 2,
            y: HEIGHT as i32,
        },
        Point {
            x: WIDTH as i32 / 2,
            y: 3 * HEIGHT as i32 / 4,
        },
        15,
        Rgb::WHITE,
        0.6,
        2,
    );

    if let Err(e) = picture.save("test".as_ref()) {
        eprintln!("Error saving image: {}", e);
        // Lets the caller know that our program failed.
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}

fn draw_tree(
    canvas: &mut Canvas,
    prev: Point,
    next: Point,
    iter: i32,
    colour: Rgb,
    angle: f64,
    branches: usize,
) {
    if iter == 0 {
        return;
    }
    canvas.draw_line(prev, next, 1, colour);
    let prev = Point {
        x: 2 * next.x - prev.x,
        y: 2 * next.y - prev.y,
    };

    if branches % 2 == 1 {
        let straight = next.rotate_and_scale(prev, 0.0);
        draw_tree(canvas, next, straight, iter - 1, colour, angle, branches);
    }

    for i in 1..=branches / 2 {
        let left = next.rotate_and_scale(prev, i as f64 * angle);
        draw_tree(canvas, next, left, iter - 1, Rgb::LEFT, angle, branches);

        let right = next.rotate_and_scale(prev, -(i as f64) * angle);
        draw_tree(canvas, next, right, iter - 1, Rgb::RIGHT, angle, branches);
    }
}
```

`canvas.rs`

```
use std::{cmp, fs::File, io::Write, path::Path};

use crate::{Point, Rgb};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Canvas {
    // Since we don't need to resize data, we can store a boxed slice, which will prevent us from
    // accidently pushing, poping, resizing, etc since those are Vec methods.
    // We can store the bytes rather than the colors, which makes writing it easier.
    data: Box<[u8]>,
    // Use usize or at least an unsigned type whereever it makes sense to do so, such as a size or
    // count. I would've changed more things to unsigned, but some of your logic depends on signed.
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
}

impl Canvas {
    pub fn set_colour(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, colour: Rgb) {
        // Using usize for parameters, we don't have to check against negative.
        if x < self.width && y < self.height {
            // Make sure to multiply by 3 here to account for directly storing the bytes...
            let offset = (self.width * y + x) * std::mem::size_of::<Rgb>();
            self.data[offset] = colour.red;
            self.data[offset + 1] = colour.green;
            self.data[offset + 2] = colour.blue;
        }
    }

    // Rather than panicing, we should return a Result, especially since it is easy because all
    // operations return io::Result.
    // Using a Path for the filename is more precise.
    pub fn save(&mut self, filename: &Path) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let mut file = File::create(filename.with_extension("ppm"))?;

        write!(file, "P6 {} {} 255 ", self.width, self.height)?;
        file.write_all(&self.data)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn new(width: usize, height: usize) -> Canvas {
        Canvas {
            width,
            height,
            data: vec![0; width * height * std::mem::size_of::<Rgb>()].into_boxed_slice(),
        }
    }

    // I didn't look much at draw_square or draw_line...
    pub fn draw_square(&mut self, center: Point, width: i32, colour: Rgb) {
        for y in cmp::max(0, center.y - width)..cmp::min(self.height as i32, center.y + width) {
            for x in cmp::max(0, center.x - width)..cmp::min(self.width as i32, center.x + width) {
                self.set_colour(x as usize, y as usize, colour);
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn draw_line(&mut self, from: Point, to: Point, width: i32, colour: Rgb) {
        if from.x == to.x {
            let startx = cmp::max(from.x - width, 0);
            let endx = cmp::min(from.x + width, self.width as i32);
            let endy = cmp::max(from.y, to.y) + 1;
            let starty = cmp::min(from.y, to.y);
            for y in starty..endy {
                for x in startx..endx {
                    self.set_colour(x as usize, y as usize, colour);
                }
            }
        } else {
            let k = f64::from(to.y - from.y) / f64::from(to.x - from.x);
            let n = f64::from(to.y) - k * f64::from(to.x);
            let lower = cmp::min(from.x, to.x);
            let upper = cmp::max(from.x, to.x) + 1;
            for x in lower..upper {
                self.draw_square(
                    Point {
                        x,
                        y: (k * f64::from(x) + n) as i32,
                    },
                    width,
                    colour,
                );
            }
            if k.abs() > 1.0 {
                let lower = cmp::min(from.y, to.y);
                let upper = cmp::max(from.y, to.y) + 1;
                for y in lower..upper {
                    self.draw_square(
                        Point {
                            x: ((f64::from(y) - n) / k) as i32,
                            y,
                        },
                        width,
                        colour,
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`point.rs`

```
const SCALING_FACTOR: f64 = 1.4 as f64;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    /// Rotates a point around self by the given angle, and scales it down.
    pub fn rotate_and_scale(self, point: Point, angle: f64) -> Point {
        // also scales down a bit
        let (sin, cos) = angle.sin_cos();
        let translated = Point {
            x: ((point.x - self.x) as f64 / SCALING_FACTOR) as i32,
            y: ((point.y - self.y) as f64 / SCALING_FACTOR) as i32,
        };
        let rotated = Point {
            x: (translated.x as f64 * cos - translated.y as f64 * sin) as i32,
            y: (translated.x as f64 * sin + translated.y as f64 * cos) as i32,
        };
        Point {
            x: rotated.x + self.x,
            y: rotated.y + self.y,
        }
    }
}
```

`rgb.rs`

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Rgb {
    pub red: u8,
    pub green: u8,
    pub blue: u8,
}

impl Rgb {
    // Makes it a little nicer to create colors, IMO.
    pub const fn new(red: u8, green: u8, blue: u8) -> Self {
        Self { red, green, blue }
    }

    pub const WHITE: Self = Self::new(255, 255, 255);
    pub const LEFT: Self = Self::new(247, 97, 74);
    pub const RIGHT: Self = Self::new(26, 121, 244);
}
```